# How to start bars from right to left using amchart?

Tags: bar-chart, amcharts

I want to start horizontal bars from right sides as below image

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [`rotate`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#rotate) to `true`, the category axis' [`position`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#position) property to `"right"` and set the value axis' [`reversed`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#reversed) property to `true`:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "rotate": true,
  "categoryAxis": {
    "position": "right",
     //...
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "reversed": true,
    // ...
  }],
  // ...
});
```

Demo below:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "rotate": true,
  "categoryAxis": {
    "position": "right"
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "reversed": true
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 395
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "categoryField": "country"
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```